# File size (6003804160) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 in node

Tags: node.js, fs

While trying to read the file size is 5GB in node.js I got this error:

> **error:**
> RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (6003804160) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 bytes

```
fs.readFile(tempfile, "utf8", function(err, filebuffer) {
      console.log(err,"filebuffer " ,filebuffer);
})
```

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 4):

2147483647 bytes is the maximum size a Buffer can have in NodeJS. Note that this operation will load all the contents of the file into memory at once. Are you sure that you want to push 5gb of data into your memory?

If you need to read files larger than that, you will need to use [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) function instead of `fs.readFile`. `fs.createReadStream` allow you to "split" the file into small(er) chunks and read one chunk at a time.

Comment: hi, thanks for suggestion, when i use const readStream = fs.createReadStream('SW_DVD9_Win_Server_STD_CORE_2016_64Bit_English_-4_DC_STD_MLF_X21-70526.ISO',{ highWaterMark : 5 * 1024 * 1024});
and during this operation i get 
 [Error: EIO: i/o error, read] {
  errno: -4070,
  code: 'EIO',
  syscall: 'read'
}

and complete file also not read. please suggest some solutions.